# Calculate pi using a Monte Carlo simulation

Tags: javascript, montecarlo, pi

I've created this script

```
const size = 500;
const iterations = 10000000;

let inside = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  var Xpos = Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
  var Ypos = Math.floor(Math.random() * size);

  var dist = Math.hypot(Ypos-Xpos, size / 2 - size / 2);

  if (dist <= size / 2) {
    inside++;
  }
}

document.write(4 * inside / iterations);
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/tr8tnxdm/3/ which places 100000000 dots in a 500, 500 grid, the dots inside the circle get noted and in the end, it gets divided by the total and multiplied by 4.

This should output a very rough estimate of pi but it doesn't and I can't figure out why. I know that it isn't because of the below or equal to since I've also tried it with only below (line 11)

Comment: "This should output a very rough estimate of pi" what values is it giving?

Comment: @phuzi it's given the total amount of dots and how many where in the circle.

Comment: Yes, but what actual values is it giving?

Comment: Its returning 3.0042532

Comment: Have you tried debugging it, check the values that gives at each stage of the calculation. That being said `Math.hypot(Ypos-Xpos, size / 2 - size / 2);` looks wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line of code:

```
var dist = Math.hypot(Ypos-Xpos, size / 2 - size / 2);
```

One argument should be difference on one axis and another one should be difference on another axis, like this:

```
var dist = Math.hypot(Xpos - size / 2, Ypos - size / 2);
```

This change greatly improves an estimate (I'm getting 3.14...)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in calculating distance. Code can be simplified:

```
  var dist = Math.hypot(Xpos, Ypos);

  if (dist <= size) {
    inside++;
  }
```

See how it works in snippet below.

```js
const size = 500;
const iterations = 10000000;

let inside = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  var Xpos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (size));
  var Ypos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (size));

  var dist = Math.hypot(Xpos, Ypos);

  if (dist <= size) {
    inside++;
  }
}

document.getElementById("pi").innerHTML = 4 * inside / iterations;
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <span id="pi"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```